# Classical set operations for java.util.Collection

Tags: java, collections, set

Is there any built-in functionality for classical set operations on the java.util.Collection class? My specific implementation would be for ArrayList, but this sounds like something that should apply for all subclasses of Collection. I'm looking for something like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> setA ...
ArrayList<Integer> setB ...
ArrayList<Integer> setAintersectionB = setA.intersection(setB);
ArrayList<Integer> setAminusB = setA.subtract(setB);
```

After some searching, I was only able to find home-grown solutions. Also, I realize I may be confusing the idea of a "Set" with the idea of a "Collection", not allowing and allowing duplicates respectively. Perhaps this is really just functionality for the Set interface?

In the event that nobody knows of any built-in functionality, perhaps we could use this as a repository for standard practice Java set operation code? I imagine this wheel has been reinvented numerous times.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Intersection is done with `Collection.retainAll`; subtraction with `Collection.removeAll`; union with `Collection.addAll`. In each case, as `Set` will act like a set and a `List` will act like a list.

As mutable objects, they operate in place. You'll need to explicitly copy if you want to retain the original mutable object unmutated.

Answer (score 16):

I would recommend [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). The [Sets](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) class seems to have exactly what you are looking for. It has a [intersection](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-) method and a [difference](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-) method.

[This presentation](http://smallwig.blogspot.com/2008/08/google-collections-presentation.html) is probably something you want to watch if you're interested.  It refers to Google Collections, which was Guava's original name.

Comment: question is asking about "classical set operations on the java.util.Collection class"

Answer (score 8):

For mutable operations see accepted answer.

For an imutable variant you can do this with java 8

subtraction

```
set1
  .stream()
  .filter(item-> !set2.contains(item))
  .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

intersection

```
set1
  .stream()
  .filter(item-> set2.contains(item))
  .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for [java.util.Set](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface (and its implementations HashSet and TreeSet (sorted))?
The interface defines removeAll(Collection c) which looks like substract(), and retainAll(Collection c) which looks like intersection.

Comment: Better link (Java 6 docs): http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Good answer.  However, these will modify one of the two sets.  If Ross wants a third set containing the solution, He'll need to clone one first and use it as the implicit variable.

Comment: mmyer, thanks for pointing that out, I still have a tab opened on Java 1.5 docs to play with Processing, and I am too often bitten by these darn framesets. Link is fixed.