# How to make Java Set?

Tags: java, collections, set

Can anyone help me?
example

- A {1,2,3}
- B {1,4,5}

Code snippet:

```
a.intersect(b).print()
// Result 1 . twin between two object

a.merge(b).print()
// Result 1,2,3,4,5
```

It is valid if I write code below?
If not, which part I have to fix?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
   Set<Integer> a = new TreeSet<Integer>();
   a.add(1);
   a.add(2);
   a.add(6);
   a.remove(2);
   a.add(1); //gak berpengaruh karena sudah ada yang 1 sebelumnya
   //mengapa begituu ? karena et adalah collection yang tidak dapat memiliki elemen kembar.
   System.out.println("A = " + a);

   Set<Integer> b = new TreeSet<Integer>();
   b.add(2);
   b.add(6);
   b.add(1);
   System.out.println("B = " + b); //hasilnya 1,2,6.
   //loh?? kok bisa ? krn sy pake TreeSet, jadi udah terurut.

   b.retainAll(a); //ini rumus intersect XD
   for (Integer i: b)
   {
       System.out.print(i);
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Solution: Use Java to connect and fetch results from http://tryruby.org.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163998/classical-set-operations-for-java-util-collection

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Like this:

```
import java.util.*;
Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
a.add( 1);
a.add( 2);
a.add( 3);
```

Or adding from an Array/ or multiple literals;  wrap to a list, first.

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[]{ 1, 4, 5};
Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<Integer>();
b.addAll( Arrays.asList( b));         // from an array variable
b.addAll( Arrays.asList( 8, 9, 10));  // from literals
```

To get the intersection:

```
// copies all from A;  then removes those not in B.
Set<Integer> r = new HashSet( a);
r.retainAll( b);
// and print;   r.toString() implied.
System.out.println("A intersect B="+r);
```

Hope this answer helps. Vote for it!

Comment: you forgot union (merge).. For that use addAll

Comment: `Arrays.asList` doesn’t work with an `int[]` array. You would need an `Integer[]` array, though, since Java 5, specifying an array creation expression is obsolete, e.g. `Arrays.asList(1, 4, 5)` does the job. But you don’t need an intermediate `List` at all, you can just use `Collections.addAll(b, 1, 4, 5);`

Comment: `Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<Integer>();
       b.addAll( Arrays.asList( array));  // not b`

// it worked! incase you already had an array which in this case is true