# How do you subtract one array of chars from another in Java?

Tags: java

Let's say I have an array, arrayA = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], 
and another array, arrayB = ["a", "d", "e"].

I want to subtract arrayB from arrayA to yield the result = ["b", "c", "f"]

This is my setup for each array:

```
char[] arrayA = new char[7];
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'f'; ++c) {
    arrayA[c - 'a'] = c;
}
char[] arrayB = new char[]{'a','d','e'};
```

(Please excuse any improper use of symbols and syntax, I'm a Ruby noob trying to learn Java simply from the Oracle tutorials. Thanks!)
edit: a word and quotes

Comment: Hint: skip arrays and move directly to collections (specifically `List`/`ArrayList`). Arrays are pretty low-level tools that you should rarely use directly in Java (except maybe for `byte[]`).

Comment: LOL this post is upvote heaven!

Comment: What do you want to happen if you have multiple identical elements in `arrayA`? What do you want to happen if there are elements in `arrayB` that don't appear in `arrayA`? Is preserving the order of the elements you keep important?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The short answer is to convert your arrays to "sets", and then use set operations on them.  I'm looking for the proper code for that right now, but you can start by checking out this post: [Classical set operations for java.util.Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163998/classical-set-operations-for-java-util-collection)

Edit: Luke657 brings up a good point.  primitive arrays are weird.  So below is the updated code:

Assuming you start with a char array (it would of course be better to start with a set, but oh well):

```
char[] arrayA = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
char[] arrayB = new char[] {'a', 'd', 'e'};
Character[] objarrayA = ArrayUtils.toObject(arrayA);
Character[] objarrayB = ArrayUtils.toObject(arrayB);
Set<T> setA = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(objarrayA));
Set<T> setB = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(objarrayB));

setA.removeAll(setB);
```

Then, to get it back to a char array:

```
Character[] result;
result = setA.toArray(result);
char[] cresult = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(result);
```

I believe this will do what you need.  The `Arrays.asList()` operation is O(1), so is efficient and not computationally expensive, so don't worry about that extra conversion.

Comment: no idea.  probably because I said I wouldn't bother posting code since user2503916 has it below.  Hmm ok so maybe I DO have an idea.

Comment: If your answer gets upvoted, i think you should include code. Future users will only have to read your answer instead of scrolling to find code. =)

Comment: yea fair enough.  I shall do so.

Comment: @Goatcat: and having to understand what you write is bad, because ...?

Comment: @Goatcat sorry, i don't really accept with you. You don't really need to post the code when you have already answered the question in words

Comment: @Goatcat Agreed, especially as the code below is a different solution, using Lists and not Sets (Which could produce two different results)

Comment: @PermGenError I think it's always good to review your answer and see if you can make it more complete. If Russell Uhl can both answer the question in words and also show an example of what he meant, it's surely a nice thing for future members. I know I'd have appreciated it. :)

Comment: @Goatcat yeah, but this answer without code doesn't make it any less.

Comment: @Russel_Uhl This looks great, thanks! Would I need to import java.util.Set or java.util.Collection or something like that? I keep getting 'Set, T, Hashset cannot be resolved to type' upon inspection.

Comment: Do you have a workaround for ArrayUtils that uses standard Java API?

Comment: @M.J.Davis yes, there are imports.  You can google the terms to find the API info on them.  I believe you need `java.util.Hashset`, `java.util.set`, and...that's it.  <T> is a generic, and should be detected as such automatically once you have the imports.  If not, remove <T> and in its place, put `<Character>`  You will also need the apache commons library for ArrayUtils.  I'm looking to see if there is an alternate, but so far, have not found one.

Comment: This and other answers involving sets seem to assume that ordering is unimportant - something that is not stated in the original question. The characters in the result array here will almost certainly have a different order to that in arrayA. For this specific case you can resolve this by using TreeSet rather than HashSet as the array contents are ordered alphabetically, but for an arbitrary ordering you'll need something else.

Comment: @GeorgeHawkins Thank you! That is pretty crucial information and coming from Ruby, I didn't know that was necessary to specify. That is what I will need to use.

Comment: but the problem with this code is if the second array has repeated items like new char[] {'a', 'd', 'e', 'd'}; then it really won't work.

Answer (score 12):

Convert them to List and call the `removeAll` method:

```
Character[] array1 = ArrayUtils.toObject(arrayA);
    Character[] array2 = ArrayUtils.toObject(arrayB);       
    List<Character> list1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array1));
    List<Character> list2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array2));
    list1.removeAll(list2);`
```

Comment: This is excellent! I did not know about `.asList()`. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This will throw runtime exception. `Arrays.asList` return un-modifiable list. You need to create a new list.

Comment: Throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` to be more concrete.

Comment: This will not compile because `Arrays.asList` doesn't take a `char[]` (or to be precise: it does, but it will return a `List<char[]>`).

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you construct a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) from `arrayA` and then call `removeAll` on it using the second array.

If the two arrays are sorted as shown in your question you can solve the problem with a single iteration over the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Repeated {

public static void main(String[] args) {
//        Collection listOne = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"));
//        Collection listTwo = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("a", "d", "e"));
 //
//        listOne.retainAll( listTwo );
//        System.out.println( listOne );

    String[] s1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
    String[] s2 = {"a", "d", "e"};
    List<String> s1List = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(s1));
    for (String s : s2) {
        if (s1List.contains(s)) {
            s1List.remove(s);
        } else {
            s1List.add(s);
        }
         System.out.println("intersect on " + s1List);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There's [`Collection.removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)).

Comment: This will likely be slower than the removeAll() methods suggested

Answer (score 2):

Arrays.asList doesn't work with primitive types like char so you have to iterate through both arrays, change them to the wrapper class Character and add them to sets. Then, you can use removeAll method.

```
Set<Character> setA = new HashSet<>();
Set<Character> setB = new HashSet<>();
for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
    setA.add(new Character(arrayA[i]));
}
for(int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++){
    setA.add(new Character(arrayB[i]));
}
setA.removeAll(setB);
arrayA = new char[setA.size()];
int i = 0;
for(Character c : setA){
    arrayA[i++] = c.charValue();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your arrays to lists (For example ArrayList) using `Arrays.asList()`. Generic sets do not take primitive types (so asList won't work on your arrays as they are now) so you can use the object Character instead like this:

```
Character a[] = {'f', 'x', 'l', 'b', 'y'};
Character b[] = {'x', 'b'};
ArrayList<Character> list1 = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(a));
ArrayList<Character> list2 = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(b));
list1.removeAll(list2);
```

Read about generic types here in case you're unfamiliar with them: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

In case you do need arrays you can use the toArray() function of ArrayList to recreate an array.