# Comparing and removing elements not present in a List and array java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have one `String` array and one `List<String>`. What I want to do is to use the variable with a larger size and use that as the basis of the values removal of the smaller variable. I also want to get the values of the larger sized variable not present in the other. Note that the reason why the two variables differ on datatype is because the `String[] group` variable is a checkbox group from a jsp page and the `List<String> existingGroup` is a ResultSet from the database. For example:

`String[] group` contains:

```
Apple
Banana
Juice
Beef
```

`List<String> existingGroup` contains:

```
Apple
Beef
Lasagna
Flower
Lychee
```

And since the size of the two variables vary, it should still correctly remove the values.

What I have so far is

```
    if(groupId.length >= existingGroup.size()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < groupId.length; i++) {
            if(! existingGroup.contains(groupId[i])) {
                if(existingGroup.get(existingGroup.indexOf(groupId[i])) != null) {
                    // I'm unsure if I'm doing this right
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < existingGroup.size(); i++) {
            // ??
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer this Stack Overflow post for [more clarity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163998/classical-set-operations-for-java-util-collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the methods the `List` interface provides.

```
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(array)); // Differences removed
```

or

```
list.retainAll(Arrays.asList(array)); // Same elements retained
```

based on your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I would start with converting your array into the `List` too. So do

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList(array);
//now you can do intersections
input.retainAll(existingGroup); //only common elements were left in input
```

Or, if you want elements which are not common, just do

```
existingGroup.removeAll(input); //only elements which were not in input left
input.removeAll(existingGroup); //only elements which were not in existingGroup left
```

Choice is yours:-)

Comment: That's great but I also need the differences between them, not only the common elements. I think my statement on the beginning of my post is vague so I rephrased it.

Comment: The `retainAll` complains that the variable must be `boolean` type. Is this the right method for getting the common elements?