# How to subtract two string arrays in java as they are shown in code

Tags: java, string

//What should I do to subtract `quan` from `objIn`?
//means quan has values 1,2,7,9 and objIn has values 5,6,7,8 then how to subtract so that result is  4,4,0,1  as i want operation quan[]=quan[]-objIn[] to be done?

```
public static void Equalizer(int i, int s, String quan[], String objIn[])
{
    int j;
    Scanner Inp = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(objIn[j]+"=");
        objIn[j]=Inp.nextLine();
    }

    for(j=0;j<s;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(quan[j]+"=");
        quan[j]=Inp.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "subtract"? Please provide sample input, expected output, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Does your scanner accept input or it just outputs to the console?

Comment: so you should use substring. First of all, convert all arrays to Strings. After that, use this: objInString.substring(0,quanString.length());

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classical set operations for java.util.Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163998/classical-set-operations-for-java-util-collection)

Answer (score 0):

There's a `subtract()` method

```
public String[] subtract(String[] sa1, String[] sa2){
  List<String> r = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < sa1.length; i++){
    if (i >= s2.length) {
      r.add(sa1[i]);
      continue;
    }
    try {
     r.add(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(sa1[i]) - Integer.parseInt(sa2[i])));  
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }       
  } 
  return r.toArray(new String[r.size()]); 
}
```

Comment: That has different semantics than what OP wants (although it seems that OP updated after you answered, so that's not info you had at the time)

Comment: This works differently than what OP wants. This functions similarly to `removeAll()`, but it appears OP wants to do something more like subtracting one matrix from another

Comment: I think OP wants to substract numbers. For example if i type 1,2,3,4, after that i type again this: 0,1,1,1, so it should result like this:
1-0,2-1,3-1,4-1 = 1,1,2,3 :) So for-each, convert string array to int array and substract each elements from both arrays. (as i understand the restriction is that arrays are the same size). EZ task

Comment: But it simpler than subtract arrays. I will remove it because OP changes the question on the fly.

Comment: ListUtils doesn't do it. it just deletes occurrences, but does not make any actions with elements at all.

Comment: @user3580294 I don't understand removeAll()? Do you have a example?

Comment: @solvator Doesn't do it is, what do you mean by it? It subtracts two arrays and that was asked originally (still in the question title :).

Comment: [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) the javadoc. Essentially, it removes all elements that the receiver object has in common with the passed argument, so after the method completes the two collections have no elements in common.

Comment: @user3580294 ok, `removeAll()` removes all, how it differs from the method above?

Comment: You linked to the answer. From the javadoc: "This differs from List.removeAll(Collection) in that cardinality is respected; if list1 contains two occurrences of null and list2 only contains one occurrence, then the returned list will still contain one occurrence."

Comment: That's right, and this is called subtraction, instead of removing everything.

Comment: Actually i want to say that if String quan[]={"1","2","3"} and      String objIn={"6","7","4"} so that answer should be string quan={"5","5","2"}...so it subtracts two string arrays....

Comment: @TSjahangiri. Do you mean that your string array is not a string array but a char array or a byte array?

Comment: Actually i want to say that if String quan[]={"1","2","3"} and String objIn={"6","7","4"} so that answer should be string quan={"5","5","2"}...so it subtracts two string arrays....as i want to do operation qua[] = stOt[] - quan[];

Comment: That is true, which is why I said `subtract()` functions *similarly* to `removeAll()`, and it still doesn't answer OP's question. OP has `int`/whatever-as-`String` arrays and wants to perform the equivalent of matrix subtraction.

Comment: so what to do?? for subtracting??

Comment: call `subtract(objIn, quan)`.

Comment: the function subtracts numbers in one array from another.

Comment: it subtracts only sbtructable parts that have the same index and remains other values unchanged.

Comment: @user3580294,@solvator does it answer the question?