# Iterate throught a collection and put all values into a list

Tags: java, collections

I have a collection `[[140], [141,143], [11], [11,22]]`
what is the best way to take these numbers and store them into a array list with no duplicates?

```
[140,141,143,11,22]
```

Comment: Do you care about the order?

Comment: Is this a collection of collecions? collection of arrays?

Comment: You should use [set operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163998/classical-set-operations-for-java-util-collection) that's basically what you need.

Comment: Order does not matter, collection of arrays.

Comment: Just stick the numbers in any [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). The duplicates will automagically disappear. Then you can create an ArrayList from the Set, if wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Collection<Collection<Integer>> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(ints,
            Arrays.asList(149),
            Arrays.asList(141, 143),
            Arrays.asList(11),
            Arrays.asList(11, 22));

    // Java 8
    List<Integer> flattenedUniqueInts = ints.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.stream()).sorted().distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Java 7, optimally using Set.
    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (Collection<Integer> sub : ints) {
        Collections.addAll(sub);
    }
```

Two solutions, one for java 8, one for java 7. In Java 8 one could be content with an `IntStream` result, using `flatMapToInt` without `collect`; using `int` instead of Integer. And maybe experiment with parallel.