# Find the uncommon, common all elements from two different array list objects in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, data-structures

I am trying to find the uncommon, common items from two different non-ordered array list objects in java. I have already read many posts about these but could not find a proper answer.

The first array list objects stores the data that are fetched from the server. The second array list objects stores the local database data.

Now I am trying to find the **common, uncommon all elements** from these two array lists. Here the array lists are generated from completely two different model classes but they have similar properties.

The equal comparison does give the common value but can't find the uncommon items from the two array lists when i put the condition as "!listA.id.equals(listB.id)".

For example:

```
for(CustomStation user1 : localStationLists) {
                            for(CustomStation user2 : serverStationLists) {
                                if(user1.getStationId().equals(user2.getStationId())) {
                                    *//*if(!user1.getTitle().equals(user2.getTitle())) {
                                        resultList.add(user1);
                                    }*//*
                                    //System.out.println(" EQUAL St ids : " + user1);
                                    resultList.add(user2);
                                }
                                else{
                                    resultList1.add(user1);
                                }
                            }
```

So, thinking whether you guys are also having the same problems?

Have been trying for last three days with different approaches but have been failed repeatedly to get a solution.

Comment: @PrerakSola added sample code. Please give some proper guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this code but you can try this:

```
for(CustomStation user1 : localStationLists) 
{
    boolean flag = false;
    for(CustomStation user2 : serverStationLists) 
    {
        if(user1.getStationId().equals(user2.getStationId())) 
        {
            if(!user1.getTitle().equals(user2.getTitle())) 
            {
                resultList.add(user1);
            }            
            resultList.add(user2);
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag == false)
    {
        resultList1.add(user1);
    }
}
```

Comment: will it give me the non-equal list of data?

Comment: `resultList1` should have the non equal data.

Comment: your answer gives me some idea. So far it looks ok for me. For further problem how can i contact with you?

Comment: your corrected code is working so far perfectly. thanks But still have one small problem. How can I get the non-equal user2.getStationId() ids out of the first equal checking condition?  ..if(user1.getStationId().equals(user2.getStationId())) 
        {...

Comment: I didn't understood. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: For this condition if(user1.getStationId().equals(user2.getStationId()) }  we are getting all the equal values. But i also want to get all the non-equal values for user2 for example say in "else" condition?

Comment: Here, we are comparing a single element of `list1` to all the elements of `list2`. So it's difficult to add the non equal element of `list2` as you may get a hit for the current element of `list2` with the next element of `list1`.

Comment: thanks. so then what will be the alternative option as i must need to get this data?

Comment: Once you have the common elements in an array. You can compare that with both previous arrays and find the non equal ones.

Answer (score 8):

These feel like set operations to me: union, overlap, and difference.

Have a look at this:

[Classical set operations for java.util.Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163998/classical-set-operations-for-java-util-collection)

Works perfectly for me.  Here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Add something descriptive here.
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 3/26/2015
 * Time: 1:27 PM
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284061/find-the-uncommon-common-all-elements-from-two-different-array-list-objects-in/29284162?noredirect=1#comment46767251_29284162
 */
public class SetOperationDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> setOne = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("A");
            add("B");
            add("C");
            add("D");
            add("E");
        }};
        List<String> setTwo = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("D");
            add("E");
            add("F");
            add("G");
        }};

        System.out.println("Set A           : " + setOne);
        System.out.println("Set B           : " + setTwo);
        List<String> base = new ArrayList<String>(setOne);
        base.retainAll(setTwo);
        System.out.println("Intersection A+B: " + base);
        base = new ArrayList<String>(setOne);
        base.removeAll(setTwo);
        System.out.println("Subtraction  A-B: " + base);
        base = new ArrayList<String>(setTwo);
        base.removeAll(setOne);
        System.out.println("Subtraction  B-A: " + base);
        base = new ArrayList<String>(setOne);
        base.addAll(setTwo);
        System.out.println("Union A union B : " + base);
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Set A           : [A, B, C, D, E]
Set B           : [D, E, F, G]
Intersection A+B: [D, E]
Subtraction  A-B: [A, B, C]
Subtraction  B-A: [F, G]
Union A union B : [A, B, C, D, E, D, E, F, G]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If your Lists contain custom classes, you have to be sure that they override equals and hashCode properly or they won't give the expected behavior.  Here's my code using a custom class that shows how it's done.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Add something descriptive here.
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 3/26/2015
 * Time: 1:27 PM
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284061/find-the-uncommon-common-all-elements-from-two-different-array-list-objects-in/29284162?noredirect=1#comment46767251_29284162
 */
public class SetOperationDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DemoPerson> setOne = new ArrayList<DemoPerson>() {{
            add(new DemoPerson("Andy", "A"));
            add(new DemoPerson("Bob", "B"));
            add(new DemoPerson("Carl", "C"));
            add(new DemoPerson("David", "D"));
            add(new DemoPerson("Ernie", "E"));
        }};
        List<DemoPerson> setTwo = new ArrayList<DemoPerson>() {{
            add(new DemoPerson("David", "D"));
            add(new DemoPerson("Ernie", "E"));
            add(new DemoPerson("Frank", "F"));
            add(new DemoPerson("Gary", "G"));
        }};

        System.out.println("Set A           : " + setOne);
        System.out.println("Set B           : " + setTwo);
        List<DemoPerson> base = new ArrayList<DemoPerson>(setOne);
        base.retainAll(setTwo);
        System.out.println("Intersection A+B: " + base);
        base = new ArrayList<DemoPerson>(setOne);
        base.removeAll(setTwo);
        System.out.println("Subtraction  A-B: " + base);
        base = new ArrayList<DemoPerson>(setTwo);
        base.removeAll(setOne);
        System.out.println("Subtraction  B-A: " + base);
        base = new ArrayList<DemoPerson>(setOne);
        base.addAll(setTwo);
        System.out.println("Union A union B : " + base);
    }
}

class DemoPerson {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public DemoPerson(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        DemoPerson that = (DemoPerson) o;

        return !(firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(that.firstName) : that.firstName != null) && !(lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(that.lastName) : that.lastName != null);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
        sb.append("'").append(firstName).append('\'');
        sb.append(" '").append(lastName).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And here's the output, still behaving as it should:

```
Set A           : [{'Andy' 'A'}, {'Bob' 'B'}, {'Carl' 'C'}, {'David' 'D'}, {'Ernie' 'E'}]
Set B           : [{'David' 'D'}, {'Ernie' 'E'}, {'Frank' 'F'}, {'Gary' 'G'}]
Intersection A+B: [{'David' 'D'}, {'Ernie' 'E'}]
Subtraction  A-B: [{'Andy' 'A'}, {'Bob' 'B'}, {'Carl' 'C'}]
Subtraction  B-A: [{'Frank' 'F'}, {'Gary' 'G'}]
Union A union B : [{'Andy' 'A'}, {'Bob' 'B'}, {'Carl' 'C'}, {'David' 'D'}, {'Ernie' 'E'}, {'David' 'D'}, {'Ernie' 'E'}, {'Frank' 'F'}, {'Gary' 'G'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I just posted the code along with the output.  I know it works.  Did you run it and try it?

Comment: see my sample code. the sample code does not work for your proposed methods. Find the intersection, subtraction from my code if you can..that will be really great answer

Comment: I have no idea what your custom classes are doing.  If you have lists of a custom class, it suggests that you didn't override equals or hashcode properly.  Mine works because String acts as expected.  Your custom classes might not be.  The problem isn't with List; it's your code.