# remove common element from two array list in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hello friends i have two arraylist **mArrayListMySkuVarients** and **mArrayListAllVarients** and i want to remove common element form these two arraylist and store it third one **mArrayListCommonVarients** so below is my code

```
        mArrayListMySkuVarients =new ArrayList<>();
        mArrayListAllVarients=new ArrayList<>();

        mArrayListCommonVarients=new ArrayList<>(mArrayListAllVarients);


 GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData mProductVarientData=new GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData();
    mProductVarientData.setSku("2");
    mProductVarientData.setColor("Red");
    mArrayListMySkuVarients.add(mProductVarientData);

    GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData mProductVarientData1=new GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData();
    mProductVarientData1.setSku("1");
    mProductVarientData1.setColor("Green");
    mArrayListMySkuVarients.add(mProductVarientData1);

    GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData mProductVarientData2=new GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData();
    mProductVarientData2.setSku("4");
    mProductVarientData2.setColor("Blue");
    mArrayListMySkuVarients.add(mProductVarientData2);




    GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData mProductVarientData3=new GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData();
    mProductVarientData3.setSku("2");
    mProductVarientData3.setColor("Red");

    mArrayListAllVarients.add(mProductVarientData3);

    GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData mProductVarientData4=new GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData();
    mProductVarientData4.setSku("1");
    mProductVarientData4.setColor("Green");

    mArrayListAllVarients.add(mProductVarientData4);

    GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData mProductVarientData5=new GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData();
    mProductVarientData5.setSku("4");
    mProductVarientData4.setColor("Blue");

    mArrayListAllVarients.add(mProductVarientData5);

    GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData mProductVarientData6=new GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData();
    mProductVarientData6.setSku("3");
    mProductVarientData4.setColor("Yellow");

    mArrayListAllVarients.add(mProductVarientData6);


for(GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData apv : mArrayListAllVarients) {
                        for (GetProductDetail.ProductVarientData pv : mArrayListMySkuVarients) {
                            if (apv.getSku() == pv.getSku() && apv.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase(pv.getColor())) {
                                mArrayListCommonVarients.remove(pv);

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

When i run above code it is not remove my duplicate value it give me all data in mt third arraylist so how can i solve this? your all suggestions are appreciable

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/29284162/3022836](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29284162/3022836)

Answer (score 0):

The setSku that you are using is accepting a string value

```
mProductVarientData4.setSku("1");
mProductVarientData5.setSku("4");
.....
```

And in the if statement you are using ==

```
if (apv.getSku() == pv.getSku() && apv.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase(pv.getColor()))
```

Use .equals() to check if you have the same object because == means that they are pointing to the same object.

Change the code to

```
if (apv.getSku().equals(pv.getSku()) && apv.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase(pv.getColor()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (apv.getSku().equals(pv.getSku()) && apv.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase(pv.getColor())) {
                            mArrayListCommonVarients.remove(pv);

                        }
```

use .equals() instal ==