# How to compare lists with duplicate values and return list with common items

Tags: java, lambda

How to implement compare(List, List) as a function that returns a list of common values without unification of duplicates.

Examples:

```
compare(List.of("1","2", "3", "1"), List.of("1", "1", "3", "4")) // [1, 1, 3]
compare(List.of("1","2", "3"), List.of("1", "3", "1")) // [1, 3]
compare(List.of("1","2", "1"), List.of("3")) // []
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the uncommon, common all elements from two different array list objects in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284061/find-the-uncommon-common-all-elements-from-two-different-array-list-objects-in)

Comment: I need to handle duplicate values.

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.  What did you try?  In the future you should show at least some work instead of just trolling for answers on the internet.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about order of result then:

```java
    private List<String> compare(List<String> l1, List<String> l2) {
        var ll = new ArrayList<>(l2);
        return l1.stream()
                .filter(ll::remove)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

Comment: ArrayList was a solution because HashSet remove duplicates in ll set. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @AkifHadziabdic changed it back.