# Find the difference between two Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

this does not look like a duplicate to existing intersection / union questions (I may wrong).

I have two ArrayLists, which contains a class that contains a value, e.g.,

```
class A {
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And my Lists are

```
ArrayList<A> first, second;
```

I want to find two indices from `first` and `second`, which first indices are points to items in `first` that the respective values only in `first` but not in `second`, and the other indices are indices in `second` that the respective values only in `second` but not in `first`.

For example (read from center rows, where has the data):

```
hit                  *   *
index of first   0   1   2   3
----------------------------------
first.value      1   3   5   7
second.value     1 2   4   6 7 8
----------------------------------
index of second  0 1   2   3 4 5
hit                *   *   *   *
```

I want two indices of `1 2` and `1 2 3 5`.

Note:

1. I prefer not to use 3rd party libraries
2. Values are integers and sorted, and I the return must also in order.
3. Lengths of `first` and `second` are uncertain - either one can be longer than the other.

Thanks.

PS: Anyone need more detail, this is a simplified version of my problem. `first` is actually a ResultSet of SQL query, which are all records on the server, `second` is a list of local record (or consider processed from another local database), what I want to do is to delete all records on the server (in `first`) that does not contained in the local database (`second`), and add those missing record to remote database. Thanks.

---

To @Tibrogargan

My target is to incrementally transfer my local database (sqlite) to remote database (MySQL). The local databases has a field called `LocalId` (no duplicate and not the primary key) and of course other contents (~10 fields), and apart from copy required fields (~5 fields) to the remote database, I also included a field to determine if the record is deleted from local database.

As other requirement, I have already read all local data into a `ArrayList`, sorted by `LocalId` on local database, and have access to all remote data via `rs`, sorted by `LocalId` on remote database.

My earlier version of code was to find the last `LocalId` on local database, and mark all records on remote database where their `LocalId` is greater than the max `LocalId` on local database. However, it was correct until I found I don't always delete the tail records on local database, so I found it is necessary to iterate all messages and compare the existence.

I don't know if there're any "better" solution but seems that if I load all local messages to remote, the performance will be horrible?

Oh, just need to mention, there are only tens of messages need to be deleted and added to remote, out from hundreds to 100+k records existing on both remote and local dataset. The logic of determine if a record on remote should be marked as deleted is rely on if the respective message (same `LocalId`) exists on local dataset.

Comment: Show your current implementation.

Comment: Apart from wanting indexes, these are just classical set operations.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163998/classical-set-operations-for-java-util-collection.  (And getting indexes is trivial)

Comment: @dambros This is a simplified version of my implementation, the current implementation has one custom class and the other is SQL ResultSet. It is almost impossible / unnecessary to include all the source code.

Comment: If they are sorted, you can walk through the shorter one (of length S), each time checking for it (using a binary search) in the longer one (of length L).  Keep track of the ones you don't find: that makes up your first list.  Keep track of the indices you don't match with in the larger one: that makes up your second list.  Takes O(S * lg(L)).

Comment: @Tibrogargan Yes I know, it would be much easier if I just want values.

Comment: @Tide Gu are the values unique?

Comment: @Tibrogargan Yes they are unique.

Comment: Then the solution seems trivial.  `sub = first.removeAll(second); for (elem : sub) { indicies.add(first.indexOf(elem)); } return indicies`

Comment: @Tibrogargan Cool! Didn't know `indexOf(elem)` before. Thought it could be difficult to find the indices :p Big thanks!

Comment: As Tibrogargan points out, this is not difficult if you just use methods like `contains`, `indexOf` and `removeAll` etc. The difficulty is doing it efficiently (`contains` and `removeAll` - particularly `removeAll` - are very slow on `ArrayList`). How big are these lists?

Comment: @PaulBoddington Mostly the size are just hundreds of records. However, there are a few instances that has > 100k records and still growing. Thanks for pointing out the performance issue, could you please draft an example to make it efficiently? Best of all, as the original data are in ResultSet, I prefer not to dump them into ArrayList - using `rs.next()` could be ideal. Thanks.

Comment: @nhouser9's done it for me. `ArrayList.removeAll(ArrayList)` is `O(n^2)` so if n > 100k it's basically not an option.

Comment: @TideGu Here's Jon Skeet's blog post on `removeAll`, `retainAll` and `containsAll`. http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/07/29/there-s-a-hole-in-my-abstraction-dear-liza-dear-liza/

Comment: Thanks @PaulBoddington, this is a quite interesting article!

Comment: @Tide Gu Your comment that these are ResultSets makes me wonder if the data is coming from a database, in which case - why aren't you using the database's operations to do this?

Comment: @Tibrogargan What do you mean by using database's operation? I will update the question for you to describe my problem better. If you have any better idea please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Tide Gu What you're trying to do is effectively set operations.  Databases are often far better suited to do this kind of thing depending on how the data is structured and what indicies exit.  It might be much easier to achieve whatever your requirement is using database operations instead of doing it in a procedural language.  (Not that I'm implying java is procedural, but what you're doing here is using it like one)

Comment: @Tide Gu The article Paul Boddington linked described a perfect example.  Java's Collection.removeAll suffers from very poor performance under certain circumstances because it makes no attempt to evaluate the cost of which code path is selected.  Depending on what you're trying to actually achieve with your data (which you don't describe) there may be queries that can do this more effectively.  It's very hard to be able to give you a concrete answer without knowing more about your database engine/data set

Comment: @Tibrogargan I have just updated my description, could you please take a look? I'm not quite understand your suggestion but it may very helpful if you can explain further with some example / pseudocode. Thank you very much.

Comment: So a small example might be to get the 'second' set of values and do something like `delete from <table> where <value> not in ( 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 )` - which should remove [3, 5] and then another query (which I can't really figure out on the fly without using a lot of unions) to get the list of values that don't exist.

Comment: @Tide Gu getting the list that already exists is simple: `select <value> from <table> where value in ( 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 )` will return [ 1, 7 ].  Should be simple to just add any row with a value that's not in that list.  Or just ignore the 2nd query entirely and do `insert into <table> values ( ... ) where not exists (select * from <table> where value = x )`

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thanks. This is very clever idea! However, I wonder what's the default length restriction of SQL statement? Like if I have 100k+ record, it is certainly not a good idea to `NOT IN ( 1, ..., 100000)` isn't it?

Comment: @Tide Gu This probably needs to be in chat or in a different question.  Yes, you will exceed the maximum length if you try too many records. You would need to break it up.  Assuming your values are sorted you could do something like `delete from table where value < x and value not in ( .... )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108117/discussion-between-tide-gu-and-tibrogargan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the arrays are sorted, you can just loop through both of them, checking for duplicates as you go. Here is some pseudocode:

```
//loop over both arrays at once
int arrayAIndex = 0;
int arrayBIndex = 0;
while (arrayAIndex < arrayA.length && arrayBIndex < arrayB.length) {
  if (arrayA[arrayAIndex] == arrayB[arrayBIndex]) {
    arrayAIndex++;
    arrayBIndex++;
  } else if (arrayA[arrayAIndex] > arrayB[arrayBIndex]) {
    addToResultB(arrayBIndex);
    arrayBIndex++;
  } else if (arrayB[arrayBIndex] > arrayA[arrayAIndex]) {
    addToResultA(arrayAIndex);
    arrayAIndex++;
  }
}

//clean up any elements which were not looked at during the above
while (arrayAIndex < arrayA.length) {
  addToResultA(arrayAIndex);
  arrayAIndex++;
}
while (arrayBIndex < arrayB.length) {
  addToResultB(arrayBIndex);
  arrayBIndex++;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. This is the most efficient solution if the lists are large.

Comment: Assuming the lists are sorted :)

Comment: This is quite similar to my existing implementation, but I was struggling at the "clean up" stage. Many thanks for your tips! I think my problem could be solved soon!

Comment: No problem! If this answer solves your problem, please accept it as a solution =)

Comment: Note that if one list is sufficiently larger than the other, my approach in the comments above is faster.